# How do I configure Tomcat 8 on Windows to allow access from external IPs?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat

I'm running Tomcat 8 on an Amazon Web Services EC2 instance. The instance's operating system is Windows Server 2012.

I am trying to use my local PC's browser to connect to Tomcat on that instance. I configured the instance's security rules for inbound traffic to allow all addresses to access both ports 80 and 8080.

I know those rules are working because I ran a simple static web server on both those ports in turn and could access it from my local desktop.

Here is the unedited Tomcat server.xml file with the comments stripped out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

One [suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/98436/why-cant-i-access-tomcat-externally) I tried was to add **address="0.0.0.0"** to Connector tag for port 8080

Another [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address) was to add **useIPVHosts="true"** to Connector tag for port 8080 and/or add **resolveHosts="true"** to Valve tag

I tried other suggestions as well but they're pretty much a mashup of the ones I've already mentioned.

Can someone please tell me how to configure server.xml to allow Tomcat 8 to accept connections from other than localhost?

Comment: @bertieb I'm not sure what makes my question opinion based. This is after reading the rules in the help center. I feel I'm asking for help on something specific, could you please point me in the right direction on how I need to modify or narrow my question? Thanks

Comment: I voted to reopen from the "primarily opinion-based" state, but please show us these "various suggestions" from which "nothing has worked". I guess you don't want us to repeat these suggestions here; but we possibly will unless you tell us what they are.

Comment: could you post the <Connector  .... /> section of the server.xml? Because normally by default tomcat should listen on all interfaces on defined port.

Comment: @Kamil I've edited my question to give more detail